# Can't set exact div width as other div, script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have responsive navigation menu and item blocks. Item blocks automatically adjusts their width as screen resolution changes(this is great). But navigation menu is in different section of page markup and don't receive the same width values as item blocks.

**My goal**: When resolution changes - script checks width of item block and then changes width of navigation menu to the same value.

**So far I have:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $( window ).resize(function() {
         Resized();
      });
    });


  function Resized() 
    {
        var block_width= $(".block_item").width();
        var width_to_set = parseInt(block_width);

        $(".header-navi-inner").css({
           'width': (width_to_set + 'px')
        });
    };
```

When I resize I can see that script executes and navigation menu changes width, but the width is not exactly the same as item block has. It is very close but it is wider for about 1px-5px based on what resolution is set.

For example:[image]

When I looked in to CSS of these elements I found that item block has such styling:

```
    float: left;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin: 2px .25%;
    position: relative;
    width: 49.5%;
    line-height: 0.8;
```

I believe `margin .25%` is causing issues because margin percentage value is calculated based on parent node. So when resolution changes parent node changes its size and also margin. That is why 1-5px difference occurs to my script?!

Is it true? How can I get exact width of element without any other added pixels?

**What I have also tried:**

```
$(".item").innerWidth();
$(".item").outerWidth(true);
```

But results were the same.

**What I have also tried 2 (UPDATE)**:

I also tried to calculate margin value and then subtract it from *width_to_set* value:

```
var parent_node = $(".twelve").width();
var margin= (main_slaider * 0.0025);
var width_to_set = parseInt(column_width) - margin;
```

But still navigation menu was wider than item blocks for 1-3px

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: That's correct :) margin could be causing issues

Comment: `padding` can also cause problems combined with the default `box-sizing:content-box`

Comment: I really feel like this question should have the css tag on it.  Because what you are trying to do (responsive design) can be achieved without js.  I mean bootstrap has a whole premade set of css tags just for responsive design, if you didn't want to roll your own.